# Type casting Boolean to Int in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a ListA which contains "one" , "two" ,"three"
I have a ListB which contains "one"

```
ListA.map(ele => ListB.contains(ele).AsInstanceOf[Int])
```

But instead of converting to int it showing error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An `asInstanceOf` cast is not a magic conversion; it just tells the compiler to shut up and believe. Then, in runtime, a proper check is introduced where if the value is not an instance of the correct class, it will throw an exception.

You probably wanted to do something like this:

```
ListA.map(ele => if (ListB.contains(ele)) 1 else 0)
```

If you find yourself doing that in many places, you can define your own function:

```
def boolToInt(b: Boolean): Int ) if (b) 1 else 0

ListA.map(ele => boolToInt(ListB.contains(ele)))
```

Or **extension method**:

```
implicit class BoolOps (private val b: Boolean) extends AnyVal {
  @inline final def asInt: Int = if (b) 1 else 0
}

ListA.map(ele => ListB.contains(ele).asInt)
```

---

BTW, `contains` in **List** is pretty inefficient, have you considered using a **Set** instead?
Also, try to follow the [style conventions](https://docs.scala-lang.org/style/).

Answer (score 0):

you can use this simple code also :

```
  val ListA=List("one","two","three")
  val ListB=List("one")

  val result : Int = if(ListA exists ListB.contains) 1 else 0
```